# Why does bundling with Rollup and linking packages locally result in an “Invalid hook call” error?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, rollup

I’m developing a component library to be released as a private NPM package. This package includes an `<Icon />` component that imports SVGs dynamically:

```
import(`../../assets/icons/${size}/${name}.svg`)
    .then(module => {
        setIcon(module);
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.error(`Icon with name: ${name} not found!`);
        setIcon(null);
    });
```

Everything works in the component library + Storybook, but when I bundle with Rollup and link the local package (`npm link`) with a local app (`npm link @scope/package-name`) and try to use the `<Icon />` component, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

I’m able to use other components that don’t rely on dynamic imports.

What’s the deal?

#### Edit

Adding details around versions and plugins being used.

```
rollup@2.38.0
rollup-plugin-copy@3.3.0
rollup-plugin-styles@3.14.0
rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2
@rollup/plugin-alias@3.1.2
@rollup/plugin-babel@5.2.2
@rollup/plugin-dynamic-import-vars@1.1.1
@rollup/plugin-eslint@8.0.1
@rollup/plugin-node-resolve@11.1.0
@svgr/rollup@5.5.0
```

React is in my `peerDependencies`:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
```

… and listed in `external` in `rollup.config.js`:

```
external: [
    'react',
    'prop-types',
],
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: yes. run npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react from mylib

Answer (score 1):

run npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react from mylib

Comment: Worked for me thanks! The intension is to link the react from the main app to the local package `npm link` within the local package.